# Help wanted, pretty please

Tags: story, steganography

> “Knock, knock” doors said (red doors from the future, do not think about it too much). "Come in please” and without moving my eyes from computer I continued: "Please sit on chair.” After that I noticed something strange. “Hi there“ said that person - "I am new here.” And it was really true. At least for me: ”I see“ and I slowly looked at that ”new person." I continued: “Can you tell me your name?" And that person started to be slightly nervous. “Well, I…” slowly began “I can't tell you that yet.” That struck me "Why so?“ but instead of answer, that person started to viewing my pictures. I noticed small calculator and paper with symbols like A=Z, A=1 and some other number combinations like 147/8 and so. ”Who is this?“ I shook my head: ”Who is what? I want to know who are you?" and that person pointed to one picture ”I mean person on this picture.” It was old photo. From past that was already long lost. ”That is one person wh…” my neck chocked "you will replace him.” And that strange person smiled. “No problem" said and some of weight on me just disappeared. “However, I need one thing“ and finally,strange person sat on chair. "I want people interested in it.” I knew this was the easiest part. I cannot loose that person. Not now. “No worry about it. Everyone will surely come. However“ I said more seriously ”You won't be able to rest much. And -of course -" more politely ”you need to respect others.” I gave into it everything i had. "Seems like a challenge“ and that person stood up. “Yes“ I said, but that person just left my office with simple "So next week“ and disappeared. There was something ”strange" about that person. But also relieving.

But still I don't know that "persons name". Can you tell me that? Please…
Misspelling not intended (I wrote it at first, but was too self confident). Tags on purpose, missing tags on purpose (riddle is only leading correct way, however it could lead also wrong way), and:

Hint 0:

> Just for clarification, there is 147/8, not 147,8 nor 147.8.

Hint 1:

> Maybe that person was from Coding University. I should use controlled Find.

Hint 2:

> To be clear if you are not sure, [where to look for 147/8](http://www.codetable.net/), only because some sites converts it to hex/octa without you knowing it (or shows invisible characters). I'm not sure, but I would say you will get same result with Alt+0XXX, but it might be only for Windows. Also you could try to find 8220/1, but that does not work in Windows.

Hint 3:

> ”Something“ = A, and “Something else” = N

Comment: We've been discussing your puzzle because it seems a tad confusing. Could you clarify that steganography is in fact the appropriate tag? And that the English mistakes are in fact just misspellings, or are they apart of the puzzle?

Comment: @n_palum yea, feel free to correct things, since I wrote in one version "persons"

Comment: But I see in chat that you see it, you just don't know what to do with it. It is easy this time. Title has complicated meaning…

Comment: ^votes and ^ticks with an editorial note: If the lack of (apparent on my browser) formatting is or isn't deliberate, please state so in an edit. If it's deliberately ambiguous, please also and thanks for a puzzle idea.

Comment: @humn I don't care about apostrophe, so I rather change it to be more obvious. And it is something where you need good eyes, but I don't think that some browsers changing it to same character. Once you know what are you looking for, it should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the person is the

> NEW FTC CHAMPION.

In the text,

> everything is "noise" apart from the quotation marks. They come in three kinds: "left", "right", and "straight". These translate to Morse code symbols: "left" is `-`, "right" is `.`, and "straight" is an inter-letter space.

[EDITED to add: the following is wrong, and is left here only because I believe in leaving my mistakes public.]

However, unless I have made a mistake

> something isn't quite right: F should be `.-..` but what actually appears is `..-.`. [EDIT: duh, no, in fact F *is* `..-.` which is what appears here. I misread the Morse code table I was using.]

(But I might well have misread.)

Comment: Is there such thing as an LTC champion?

Comment: Whoops! I did misread, but not in the way I thought I might have.

Comment: I wanted to create it with some Book text, but I was unable to find any text with enough direct/quoted speech - that made it harder :/